# Автоматичекая отправка email каждые 30 минут или типа того

Tags: python, windows, email, авторизация, рассылка

Есть 2000 маилов, и есть информация (не спам!). Какую программу посоветуйте (может быть бесплатная). Или готовые скрипты для написания в python к примеру

Comment: https://python-scripts.com/send-email-smtp-python

Comment: Гугли `mailchimp`-like решения.

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте этот код

```
 from tkinter import *
    import smtplib
    root = Tk()
    base_of_mails = ["****@gmail.com"]
    def send():
               gmail_user = "******@gmail.com"
               gmail_password = '*********'

               to = "****@gmail.com"
               subject = 'Hi user!!!'
               body = ""
               email_text = """\
               From: %s
               To: %s
               Subject: %s

               %s
               """ % (sent_from, ", ".join(to), subject, body)
               for i in base_of_mails:
                          server = smtplib.SMTP_SSL('smtp.gmail.com', 465)
                          server.ehlo()
                          server.login(gmail_user, gmail_password)
                          server.sendmail(sent_from, i, email_text)
                          server.close()
               root.after(nmilsecs,send())
    mainloop()
```